# Jsoup redirect has not the same behaviour than browser redirect

Tags: redirect, jsoup

I'm facing a server through Jsoup (latest v 1.10.2) to extract some data from a page.
This server is opened to anonymous users but it uses a redirect chain to grant a session ID to each user.

This is the sequence, I got by browser:

1. First request to http://SERVER_HOST/page 
    
   resp: 302 Redirect to Location http://SSO_SERVER
2. Follow redirect, opening http://SSO_SERVER 
   resp: 302 Redirect to Location http://SERVER_HOST/page?sessionID=123456
3. Follow redirect, opening http://SERVER_HOST/page?sessionID=123456 
   resp: 200 :)

Unexpectedly with Jsoup, the redirect chain fails. Look at the difference into the step 2:

1. First request to http://SERVER_HOST/page (without cookies) 
    
   resp: 302 Redirect to Location http://SSO_SERVER
2. Follow redirect, opening http://SSO_SERVER
   resp: 302 Redirect to Location /shared/SSO/http%3a%2f%2SERVER_HOST/page%3dsessionID=123456
3. Follow redirect, opening http://SSO_SERVER/shared/SSO/http%3a%2f%2SERVER_HOST/page%3dsessionID=123456
   resp: 400 not found :(

At the step 2, redirect location in server response start with "/" not with "http://", so at the step 3 it connects to the wrong host.

Why at the step 2, I got a different location in server response according the request belongs to browser or to JSoup?

I set JSoup request the same headers of browser request:

```
Response response = Jsoup.connect(link) 
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36")
                    .header("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8") 
                    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch") 
                    .header("Accept-Language", "it,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6")
                    .header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
                    .method(Method.GET)
                    .followRedirects(true).execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in [Jsoup.Connect()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect-java.lang.String-) in how a query string in a redirect header was handled.

That's fixed now in [this commit](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/commit/56a728d482ce0c88cd9513eca1e7c7585f0718f9). You can build off HEAD to get access to the fix, and it will be available in the next release (1.10.3).

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my question. I'm just using ver 1.10.2.
I'm wondering if a server could recognize a request from JSoup to build a different response than browser request.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. Anything's possible, but with the UA being set it wouldn't be my guess. It looks like something's not being decoded or encoded correctly. I can't debug it for you without the URL or another way to replicate it. You might like to open an issue and contact me offline if you'd like.

Comment: You can checkout https://github.com/fabioformosa/jsoup-bug-reproduce.git to reproduce. Thanks a lot Jonathan.

Comment: Thanks @FabioFormosa. Fixed (and will update answer)

Comment: Thank you for this. I know it's an opensource project but the fact that they haven't released a new version to fix this in four months is sad.